# Finding the size of the data pointed by char pointer

Tags: c++, c

I want to get the size of the data which is pointed by a char pointer. I understand that if I use sizeof it returns the size of the pointer. But it is requirement of using sizeof() instead of strlen() and char* instead of char array.

```
char *data = "Hello, World";
```

Comment: Whats wrong with `strlen`?

Comment: An Existing code needs it to be sizeof(). Nothing is wrong with strlen. But is there a way I can use sizeof().

Comment: I dont think its possible.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen()` returns length of string until 0 byte is encountered. In other words, your can have:

```
char buf[1024] = "abc";
```

and then `strlen(buf) == 3`, while `sizeof(buf) == 1024`.

`sizeof` is giving you accurate size of memory needed to store variable.

However, `sizeof(ptr)` the way you are using it will not give you proper size. It will probably be 4 or 8 depending on your platform, regardless of string length - because `sizeof` returns memory needed to keep the pointer, not what is points to.

Answer (score 0):

A `char` pointer points to one `char.` That `char` may be followed by zero or more `char`s. It depends entirely on what your application is using it for. It *may* point to a null-terminated string, in which case you can use `strlen()`. If it doesn't your question is essentially meaningless, or else the answer is `sizeof char` which by definition is `1.`

Answer (score 0):

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    `char *d="hello,kl";`
    `cout << sizeof(d);`
    //This will return only 4 SO the best way is to create your 
own function for this and call it whenever you needed it.
}

No in c++ you cannot override sizeof operator .So create a user definded method and make it to count the char and instead callin sizeof call your function

Comment: Do you mean overiding sizeOf

Answer (score 0):

Why not do

```
   char data[] = "Hello World";
   printf("%d\n", sizeof(data));
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this dummy ways to get that

```
int i = 0;
while (data[i] != '\0')
      i++;
```

i is the size of data in variable data